# I created a application in android studio. I received the error in the picture. I tried everything and cant resolve it

Tags: java, android, user-interface, mobile

I created a application in android studio. I received the error in the picture. I tried everything and cant resolve it.

[image]

Comment: Add design dependency - implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'

Comment: I tried it and it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Watch this film about `Android Studio rendering problems` in youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEE3ZChGqVU

Another way is:

click on `Invalidate Cashes/Restart ...` in `File` menu.

Comment: I did but I have a newer version of android studio and that button isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

just click to refresh you layout

[image]